# Where in the linux kernel are system calls dispatched?

Tags: kernel, system-calls

Firstly, I should mention that I'm working with the 2.6.32 Linux kernel. I'm looking for the code in the source that executes the proper system call based on the system call ID (defined in `/linux/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S`). From my understanding, system calls are done through an interrupt, with the system call ID in the eax register. So the kernel must service the interrupt, and execute the appropriate system call based on the ID in the eax register.

Where can I find in the source code where this takes place? Even just some guidance on what I should be looking for to find this code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe you're looking for system_call() in /arch/x86/kernel/traps.c - this function is what saves the system call number and all the CPU registers, but it happens as an assembly linkage in /arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S in your case (x86). Take a look at Chapters 6 and 10 in O'Reilly's Understanding the Linux Kernel book if you're interested in learning more about the way this linkage happens.